# Nginx configuration always takes default block

Tags: nginx, dns, webserver

I'm setting up a nginx for mutiple (3) domains. As i understood, the server should take the correct server block, when the server_name matches. In my case i always end up in the default block. When i remove it, it takes the next block. Not regarding the used domain.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen *:443 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    root /app/app-cluster/public;
    index index.php;
    server_name domain1.com;


    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
            $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            internal;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # 
    managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; 
    # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
            root /app/placeholder;
            index index.html;
            server_name domain2.com domain3.com

            listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
            listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # 
            managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; 
   # managed by Certbot
            include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
   }
```

Comment: missing ending `;` in your laster server's server_name instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx config contains some bugs.

For example first server block doesn't configured for SSL at all.

So I assume you use HTTP for testing (not HTTPS) and the first server block catch all requests.